# Trying to follow a turorial code and I'm having path error

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm a beginner trying django for the first time trying to map my urls together, but after following the necessary steps the django installation page keeps on showing on my browser.

*for my project app*

```
from django import path
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index )
]
```

*for my parent app*

```
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

for my project views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('good sir')
```

settings.py file is below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are isung the incorrect `include` for your parent app urls.

Instead of importing from `xml.etree.ElementInclude` import from `django.urls`

Also remove `from django import path` the path you need to use for the urlpatterns is the one from `django.urls`

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Your code works for me, if its still not working, please share your settings.py file, did you make sure to add the new app to the INSTALLED_APPS section?

Comment: Yes I did, but it's still not working sir and I've also shared the settings.py file in addition